# Inline radio buttons not aligned consistently when changing margin-top in shiny in R

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to increase the spacing to the top of inline radio buttons in my shiny UI, but when I add css formatting, it formats the first one differently than any of the following ones. It's still adjusting the margin for them, but at a smaller value than the first one. What am I missing?

```
shinyApp(
  ui <-fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        tags$style(HTML("
#          .radio-inline {margin-top: 10px;}
                        ")),
        radioButtons("selection", label=NULL,inline = TRUE,c("A", "B", "C"),selected = "A"),
        style = "padding: 5px; margin:0px;"),
  )),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image: default radio buttons]

```
shinyApp(
  ui <-fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        tags$style(HTML("
          .radio-inline {margin-top: 10px;}
                        ")),
        radioButtons("selection", label=NULL,inline = TRUE,c("A", "B", "C"),selected = "A"),
        style = "padding: 5px; margin:0px;"),
  )),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image: adjusted margin-top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is the CSS property `margin-top: 0px` for the elements `.radio-inline + .radio-inline`, and the following buttons are such elements. So you have to also set `margin-top: 10px` for `.radio-inline + .radio-inline`:

```r
        tags$style(HTML("
          .radio-inline, .radio-inline+.radio-inline {margin-top: 10px;}
        "))
```